# Changing MySQL details in Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I've just put my first Symfony project into production and I'm having trouble with database connection details not updating.

I've changed the MySQL details in parameters.yml to the correct ones, but when I try to reload the page and look in my logs it shows the old database connection details still.

I've tried:

```
php app/console cache:clear 
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
doctrine:cache:clear-metadata      
doctrine:cache:clear-query      
doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

What am I missing, why are the old MySQL details still being used?

Comment: `rm -rf app/cache/*`, `rm -rf app/logs/*` and `app/console router:debug`

Comment: How did you deploy your app? Simply by copying files over FTP or using a tool like capifony?

Comment: @Johann I used dploy.io via FTP. Cache delete doesn't seem to work either, already given that a go too